# Cocoa WebKit - detecting CSS rollover/hover

Tags: css, cocoa, webkit, webview

I have a WebView displaying a HTML page, linking to a CSS file.

The CSS file makes use of the pseudoclasses :active and :hover for rollover effects.

Q. How can I tell, in my WebView, when :active and :hover have been called?  I would like to intercept these calls and act on them programmatically within Cocoa.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:active and :hover aren't calls; they're CSS pseudo-classes, for use in CSS selectors. You use them in CSS to *select* elements to style. They're adjectives, not verbs.

Try adding JavaScript event handlers to the elements instead. You can use a WebScriptObject to project some of your Cocoa methods into the JavaScript space for use from the event handlers.

Comment: Yeah what he said. :active is just onmousedown and :hover is onmouseover, more or less

Comment: Thanks for the help. I went with the WebScriptObject approach, calling myCococa code on mouseOver and onClick event handlers. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

I'm looking in the 2.2 SDK docs, and I don't see anything in the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol. The best hope of accomplishing this maybe the instance method in `UIWebView` called `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`. Unfortunately that would probably imply some kind of polling, as there seems to be no way to define an Objective-C method that JavaScript could call back on for such an event.  I might be wrong, but I don't think it can be done (in 2.2).

Comment: “2.2 SDK”? :hover, in particular, would not make much sense on a touch-based device. I think it's reasonable to assume that the questioner is talking about the Mac.